# How to create new file extension and associate an application with it in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I want to **create a new file extension** named ".emsof" and **associate any text editor with it** like notepad++ in windows 8.1

Moreover all of these files should be searched by having filter of "*.emsof" like any other ordinary files.

Please guide me about how to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: I am working with Visual C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an empty file like `myfile.emsof`.
2. Double-click it
3. Select Notepad++ as default program.

Comment: I tried this. I tried to create a new text document and renamed it with "anything.emsof". But then when I checked it's properties, it was actually "anything.emsof.txt". So no new extension was created.

Comment: If you're going to do it this way, you need to make sure you set your file extensions to showing, then rename it. Alternately you can create a file using Notepad and save it as `"anything.emsof"` (yes, the quotes are necessary), then double-click your new file and set Notepad++ as the default program.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked, but now how to save any file with .emsof extension and also to filter .emsof files in open file dialogbox (Like we can filter .doc or .txt files)??